# jquery animate in loop not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I've looked at seemingly similar animate issues but none of them seems to quite get me to the solution. I am trying to animate a bubble sort loop to show the moving numbers but somehow this does not work.
The loop, not animated, which works is:

```
var locations = [ '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'];
function bubbleSort2 () {
    do {
        swapped = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < locations.length-1; i++) {
            if (parseInt($('#' + locations[i]).text()) > parseInt($('#' + locations[i+1]).text())) {
                $('#' + locations[i] + '>p').appendTo($('#setaside'));
                $('#' + locations[i+1] + '>p').appendTo($('#' + locations[i] ));
                $('#setaside>p').appendTo($('#' + locations[i+1]));
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    } while(swapped);
}
```

When I try to use the animation features, I am probably botching things.  With various tweaks, I can get a single pass to animate correctly but not the loop.  The non working loop, which might explain what I trying to do is:

```
var locations = [ '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'];
function bubbleSort2 () {
    do {
        swapped = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < locations.length-1; i++) {
            if (parseInt($('#' + locations[i]).text()) > parseInt($('#' + locations[i+1]).text())) {
                $('#' + locations[i]).fadeOut("slow", function(){
                    $('#' + locations[i] + '>p').appendTo($('#setaside'));
                })  ;
                $('#' + locations[i+1]).fadeOut("slow", function(){
                    $('#' + locations[i]).fadeIn("slow", function (){
                        $('#' + locations[i+1] + '>p').appendTo($('#' + locations[i] ));
                    }) ;
                }) ;
                $('#' + locations[i+1]).fadeIn("slow", function (){
                    $('#' + locations[i+1] + '>p').appendTo($('#' + locations[i] ));
                })  ;
                $('#setaside>p').appendTo($('#' + locations[i+1]));
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    } while(swapped);
}
```

The full HTML, which works, is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var locations = [ '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'];
        function bubbleSort2 () {
            do {
                swapped = false;
                for (var i = 0; i < locations.length-1; i++) {
                    if (parseInt($('#' + locations[i]).text()) > parseInt($('#' + locations[i+1]).text())) {
                        $('#' + locations[i] + '>p').appendTo($('#setaside'));
                        $('#' + locations[i+1] + '>p').appendTo($('#' + locations[i] ));
                        $('#setaside>p').appendTo($('#' + locations[i+1]));
                        swapped = true;
                    }
                }
            } while(swapped);
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<button onclick="bubbleSort2()">Bubble Sort</button>

<div class="hidden" id="setaside"> </div>

<div id="1"> <p>55</p>  </div>
<div id="2"> <p>90</p> </div>
<div id="3"> <p>33</p> </div>
<div id="4"> <p>21</p> </div>
<div id="5"> <p>80</p> </div>
<div id="6"> <p>111</p> </div>
<div id="7"> <p>11</p> </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: To clarify a bit more... I'd like each number to fade, then appear in it's new slot.  I'd like the changes to be slow so as to be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/6dug8ywk/3/)

HTML

```
<button>Bubble Sort</button>
<div id="to-sort">
    <div id="1">
        <p>55</p>
    </div>
    <div id="2">
        <p>90</p>
    </div>
    <div id="3">
        <p>33</p>
    </div>
    <div id="4">
        <p>21</p>
    </div>
    <div id="5">
        <p>80</p>
    </div>
    <div id="6">
        <p>111</p>
    </div>
    <div id="7">
        <p>11</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function doSort() {
    var $divs = $('#to-sort').children(),
        arr = [];

    if ($divs.length) {
        $divs.each(function (k, v) {
            arr.push(parseInt($(v).find('p').text(), 10));
        });

        var sorted = arr.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a - b;
        });

        var timing = 200;
        $divs.each(function (k, v) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(v).find('p').fadeOut(500, function () {
                    $(v).find('p').text(sorted[k]).fadeIn(500);
                });
            }, 500 + timing);
            timing += 200;
        });
    }
}

$('button').click(doSort);
```

Comment: your code does a sort first and then, separately does the remove and replace using fades. This does not allow me to show the pairwise swaps in the animation, which is what I am trying to do. Any ideas  on how to animate the pairwise swaps?

Comment: I do want the fade in and out.  What I want is to illustrate is the pairwise swaps in a bubble sort.  Take a look at the animated gif at:  [link] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)

Comment: Ah okay I was not familiar with bubble swap. I'll update tomorrow when I'm on.